# What combination of Steering Sensitivity and Non-linearity minimizes turning during straight-line 140 kph driving?

Tags: american-truck-simulator

Assume:

1. I use just my keyboard. I have no steering wheel and dislike using the mouse to steer.
2. I'm using a Car Mod, not a truck.
3. I don't want to slow down.

I like to drive 140 kph on highways, but something's amiss! Even on straight roads, every 5 seconds, the car stops going straight and drifts towards the lane markers. To keep the car in the lane, I must push <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> on my keyboard, but a single keystroke turns the car too much, especially if the highway isn't straight. But I want to push <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>D</kbd> as little as possible on straight roads! What positions for

1. 'Steering sensitivity'
2. 'Steering non-linearity'

fit this driving style? [Here's source for screen-shot](https://forum.scssoft.com/viewtopic.php?p=496006&sid=29aa5823b5d3cdf05934df335df7b7fd#p496006).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I use just my keyboard. I have no steering wheel and dislike using the mouse to steer.

You can't change the Steering sensitivity or Steering non-linearity settings when using a keyboard because they are exclusive to analog controls (gamepad and/or steering wheel).

> I'm using a Car Mod, not a truck.

The Prism3D game engine of Euro Truck Simulator 2 and American Truck Simulator is not meant to be used with cars, this can cause weird physics when driving anything other than trucks and busses.

Comment: Then why do "Steering sensitivity or Steering non-linearity " appear when I chose "Keyboard only"?

Comment: Keyboards are digital devices (keys are either on or off), so is obvious that those settings are exclusive for analog controllers. If a user knows what he is doing, he doesn't need this to be explained.